# VBScript from outlook to Create files/folders on network drive

Tags: vb.net, vba, vbscript, outlook

my first post here but I've been lurking for a long time. I'm working for a company that is using Outlook's VB to macro everything they're doing from custom Task Forms. Well I want to add to this by being able to activate a sub that will:

1. Create a folder on our local server/network drive (where everyone has permissions)
2. Copy Files and folders from a pre-made "template" folder to a new destination
3. Rename files in the new directories with variable names

Currently I'm at:

```
Dim     fso
Dim     sourceFol
Dim     DestFol
Dim     variable1
Dim     variable2

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If ClientCode = "1" Then
    sourceFol = "\\S:\sourcepath"
    DestFol = "\\S:\destination\"& variable1 &" - "& variable2                                              
    ElseIf ClientCode = "2" Then
    sourceFol = "\\S:\sourcepath"
    DestFol = "\\S:\destination\"& variable1 &" - "& variable2                                              
        ElseIf ClientCode = "3" Then
        sourceFol = "\\S:\sourcepath"
        DestFol = "\\S:\destination\"& variable1 &" - "& variable2          
End If

If Error Then
    WScript.Echo "Error: " & Err.Number
    WScript.Echo "Source: " &  Err.Source & "Description:" & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
    Else
    'Cancel
End If
```

The only problem is that I'm getting nothing from this, no reaction, no error, no thinking from what I'm seeing. Seeing as this is only number 1 on my list and I'm getting nothing it's very frustrating. Anyone have any good tips, pointers, or things to check in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Remove your on error resume next and rerun it. You're not handling errors anywhere which is why you have no idea what they are.

Comment: Your paths should probably look like `\\Server\sourcepath`

Comment: The `Else If` is one of your issues. The VB languages use `ElseIf` instead. But I agree with Nathan. Disable `On Error Resume Next`. It really shouldn't be needed at all in this section.

Comment: Else if should have generated a syntax error that is not ignorable. Echo out the err.number as you program only does something if it's 53 (and after getting an err.number you then have to go err.clear) so if 76 your program will fail silently (as your error may be Path Not Found 76).

Comment: So I have edited my code to reflect what you guys are telling me here, but I'm still getting the same thing, nothing. My other scripts have successfully opened files on the server, edited excel cells, saved, and closed, so I know there's no problem with that side of accessing the server and modifying at least. Plus it doesn't seem to matter if I have the destination as "\\server:\path" or not "server:\path"

Comment: Needs more information. I've never seen a network path such as \\S:\ succeed in code. It is your network mapped drive, but it would be utilized such as S:\sourcepath. 

is Client Code ever activated outside of the source code you provided? Because if it is not populated then it would bypass all of your code automatically and return 0 results. 

Are you utilizing the FSO object in other parts of the code or is it just a placemarker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim fso
Dim clientcode
Dim variable1
Dim variable2
Dim Folder

ClientCode = Trim(Item.UserProperties("Client"))

If ClientCode = "1" Then
    folder = "R:\path"& variable1 &"-"& variable2
    ElseIf ClientCode = "2" Then
    folder = "R:\01 - CHA\"& variable1 &"-"& variable2
        ElseIf ClientCode = "3" Then
        folder = "R:\03 - REOR\"& variable1 &"-"& variable2
End if

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fso.FolderExists(folder) Then
        fso.CreateFolder (folder)
        MsgBox "Folder Successfully Created and Named"
    Else
        MsgBox folder & " already exists!", vbExclamation, "Folder Exists"
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This code needs to go a long way. But here's a revision of the code so you can get output.

```
Dim     fso
Dim     sourceFol
Dim     DestFol
Dim     variable1
Dim     variable2
Dim     result

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If ClientCode = "1" Then
    sourceFol = "\\S:\sourcepath"
    DestFol = "\\S:\destination\"& variable1 &" - "& variable2                                              
    result = "Succeeded in string set: 1"
ElseIf ClientCode = "2" Then
    sourceFol = "\\S:\sourcepath"
    DestFol = "\\S:\destination\"& variable1 &" - "& variable2                                              
    result = "Succeeded in string set: 2"
ElseIf ClientCode = "3" Then
    sourceFol = "\\S:\sourcepath"
    DestFol = "\\S:\destination\"& variable1 &" - "& variable2
    result = "Succeeded in string set: 1"
Else
    result = "Client Code did not match comparison results [" & ClientCode & "]"
End If

If Err.Number<>0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error: " & Err.Number
    WScript.Echo "Source: " &  Err.Source & "Description:" & Err.Description
    Err.Clear
Else
    wscript.echo result
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for the visual on the Err sections, however I'm still not getting output at all, and I'm feeling like I've made some rookie/dumb mistake somewhere...I have everything declared, the cmd_click() options for the button that will be used, and am still getting no response.

Comment: Are you programming it directly in the outlook macro fields?

Comment: These are being used in a custom task form, directed from a clickable button. They Can be run from the macro buttons as well. I did figure this one out now with a bit different approach. My troubles now lie with getting files inside of folders moved and renamed.

Comment: I'm glad that you figured this out. I'm sorry that we couldn't better assist you. You can find some direction on file moving here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wcf3ba6(v=vs.84).aspx ....Note: the move command allows rename on moving. "c:\originalfolder\oldfilename.txt", "C:\newfolderlocation\newfilename.txt"